# Resize .GIF image

Tags: java, image, draw, gif, image-resizing

I have an animated `.GIF` image that I want to resize in java, but when trying to use the traditional methods, it does not seem to work:

```
ImageIcon esclamativoMid = null;
//... search my file...
if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("esclamativo.gif"))
    esclamativoMid = new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath());
myEnumMap.put(Resolution.MID, esclamativoMid);

for(Resolution r: Resolution.values()){
    if(r != Resolution.MID){
        int w = esclamativoMid.getIconWidth()*(r.ordinal()+1)/2;
        int h = esclamativoMid.getIconHeight()*(r.ordinal()+1)/2;
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)bi.createGraphics();
        g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
        g2d.drawImage(esclamativoMid.getImage(), 0, 0, w, h, null);
        myEnumMap.put(r, new ImageIcon(bi));
    }
}
```

When I try to display the image using that code:

```
new JLabel(myEnumMap.get(currentRes));
```

I get the `.GIF` only if `Resolution.MID` (I.E. the image loaded directly from file).

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple image-scaling library for Java called imgscalr.

The library implements a few different approaches to image-scaling and will either pick the most optimal approach for you if you ask it to, or give you the fastest or best looking (if you ask for that).

Usage is dead-simple, just a bunch of static methods. The simplest use-case is:

```
BufferedImage scaledImage = Scalr.resize(myImage, 200);
```

All operations maintain the image's original proportions, so in this case you are asking imgscalr to re-size your image within a bounds of 200 pixels wide and 200 pixels tall and by default it will automatically select the best-looking and fastest approach for that since it wasn't specified.

Comment: I have tried it, seem good for other image, but the '.GIF' image is fixed :(